# CI artifacts are not uploaded if the stage failed even with `when: always` in the config

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I use powershell and msbuild for both build and test stages.

The configuration for the test stage is like this:

```
test:
  stage: test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    name: "${CI_BUILD_STAGE}_${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}"
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - TestResults/
  dependencies: 
    - build
  script:
    - ./.gitlab-ci/Test.ps1
  tags: 
    - powershell
    - msbuild
```

On successful test run (Test.ps1 returns 0) it uploads the artifacts as it should:

```
Uploading artifacts...

TestResults/: found 15 matching files              
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok

Build succeeded
```

However if the test run was was failed it just fails and doesn't upload anything:

```
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

**SOLVED**

As [cascaval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155808/ci-artifacts-are-not-uploaded-if-the-stage-failed-even-with-when-always-in-th?noredirect=1#comment63744069_38155808) suggested I had to update the runner.

Comment: The `when` config option of `artifacts` is very new. It requires GitLab >= 8.9 and GitLab Runner >= 1.3.0. Makes sure you meet the requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I got runner 1.2.0, the updated one works

Comment: Thanks a lot got exactly the same issue... would never have found that!